# Download profile photo from Facebook, Linkedin and Google+ in Asp.Net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, google-plus, linkedin-api

I have some url, for example :

```
var JackieChanFacebookPage = "https://www.facebook.com/jackie";
```

or

```
var JasonStathamFacebookPage = "https://www.facebook.com/JasonStatham";
```

or

```
var BillGatesLinkedInPage = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates";
```

or

```
var JonSkeetGooglePlusPage = "https://plus.google.com/+JonSkeet/posts"
```

How can I extract profile photo from all of the above links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extract the profile picture from a link.
You need to use facebook apis, to manipulate facebook data.